# Setting all QLineEdits to readOnly

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I am trying to make all of my QLineEdits(I have about 150) read-only, is there a way to do this without going through and setting each individually? I was hoping I could do something like `QLineEdit::setReadOnly(true);` in my constructor but I get a compiler error saying it is an illegal call of non-static member function.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Use `QObject::findChildren()`, like this:

```
QList<QLineEdit*> l_lineEdits = ui->frame->findChildren<QLineEdit*>();

foreach (QLineEdit* l_lineEdit, l_lineEdits) {
    l_lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);
}
```

In this example the `ui->frame` is the parent widget of all the QLineEdits. Just change it to yours.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to inherit from `QLineEdit` and call `setReadOnly(true)` in its constructor. Now instead of creating object of `QLineEdit`you create objects of your custom `MyQLineEdit`. If you need to change this property dynamically then i guess there is no way but to store references to all of them in some array and traverse that to toggle this property.