# QLineEdit readOnly disables clear button as well

Tags: python, pyside2, qlineedit

Essentially  this post describes the problem however the answers are for c++ and I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in python.

Turning a lineedit into readOnly mode also disables the clearButton and I wondered if it is possible to keep the clearButton functionality active.
Is it possible to extend the action that gets triggered on a clearButton click with some custom functionality (if it is possible to access the clearbutton at all)?

- [Setting all QLineEdits to readOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695534/setting-all-qlineedits-to-readonly)
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [`readOnly`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#readOnly-prop) is set to QLineEdit it disables QToolButton (clear button), so the solution is to enable it, and for this you must obtain the button using the [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) method:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
        text="Stack Overflow", readOnly=True, clearButtonEnabled=True
    )
    le.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolButton).setEnabled(True)
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the precise answer